# Changing direction of Physics2D.gravity

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I'm currently trying to change the direction of gravity to left-right in my 2D game on Unity. I read up a little about it and here is my code:

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {

        if (gravLeft){
            gravLeft = false;
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(1.0f, 0);
        }

        else {
            gravLeft = true;
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(-1.0f, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want the gravity to reverse everytime I press the spacebar. But right now, the code is not doing anything - the gravity is still downwards.

I've already checked everything, and I have definitely attached the script to the gameObject. The gameObject also has a Box Collider 2D and a Rigidbody 2D attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Wait guys, my bad! It actually works but I've set the velocity too low. I set it to 10f and now it works fine! I'll leave the code here for anyone who needs to reverse gravity on Physics2D. (Or should I just delete this question? So sorry about the spam post)